# How to set Visual Studio 2010 default browser once and for all (Browse With does not persist)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In work via a desktop remote connection, and the default browser is set to Chrome. But I am running a Silverlight application that requires IE to function properly.

Every time I log in (after having logged off) in the virtual machine, visual studio does not remember that I set its default browser to IE, via the "`Browse With`" solution you will find googling.

In other words, the "`Browser With`" solution is good but it does not persist. I assume visual studio always take window's default browser (in my case Chrome), hence changing it to IE should make my VS always run with IE as well - but I do not want IE to be my default browser.

Isn't there a config setting somewhere where this can be set, once and for all ?

Comment: I actually did not read Hanselman's blog post till the end. The answer might be [there](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx).

Comment: [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx) describes the steps to a solution - and seems someone already created an implementation. I just can't find the extension on visual studio online gallery. Can anyone ?